# Facebooker2 template issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker

When i include fb_connect_async_js javascript helper it is throwing an 
error , Facebooker 2 don't have action view template. Could you please tell 
me how handle this situation . 
undefined local variable or method `fb_connect_async_js' for 
ActionView::Base
Thanks, 
Srini

Answer (score 0):

try add require 'facebooker2' in environment.rb and rake gems:install